# Junit Unit Testing For Splash to MainActivity

Tags: android, unit-testing

I want to test that my app is going from splash to main activity.
    Now I want to see that the when I start main activity after splash activity that time the object of main activity is not null or my app is running very fine.

Please Help me.....
Thank you....

Comment: What's? How can it be null?

Comment: I am just testing that it is null or not.

Comment: Ur activity will be not null. You doesn't create activity instance, only specify it for OS. Of course, if android managers work normally)

Comment: Sorry dear, but you are not getting me. I want to test my app using j-unit testing so i want to need a block of code which show how to test when my app going from splash to main activity.

Comment: If just you want to check whether activity launched then you can check current activity instance type or activity back stack

Comment: You know about J-Unit testing of an app?

Comment: Yeah, I know. You cannot use JUnit for activity testing. You need to use android testing wrap for JUnit.

Comment: Read [it](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/testing/ui-testing/espresso-testing.html)